# Couchbase Connector in ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory

Hi we are using this credential string in JSON format: [{"user": "JSmith", "pass":"access123"}, {"user": "Admin", "pass":"simba123"}]

But the create button doesn’t even light up yet. Do you have any demos or detailed instructions on how to make this work

Whats the format to use when connecting to CouchBase?
is this what we enter in connection strong?
[{"user": "JSmith", "pass":"access123"}, {"user": "Admin", "pass":"simba123"}]
in JSON FORMAT?

Tried connecting with ADF Preview Connector. the create button does not light  up

Answer (score 0):

I tried at my end `create` button is working fine. Kindly retry once. Consider restarting browser.
[image]